# "read ECONNRESET" error from events.js

Tags: javascript, sql, compiler-errors, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord Bot using JavaScript, and it's been working fine for months. However, it recently started giving me an really odd error when I leave it running overnight. I would give you all of my code, but it's rather large, and the error won't explain where in my code the error is, or if it's even in my code. Here's the error:

```
events.js:183
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 ^
 Error: read ECONNRESET
   at _errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
   at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:615:25)
```

I recently added some SQL to my bot, but I'm not 100% sure that it has anything to do with that; I added the SQL about a week ago, and the bot only now started acting up. Thanks in advance for any help, advice, or reasons as to why this might be happening. (My code, by the way, is called index.js, not events.js.)

Comment: Are you listening for the "error" event on the client object?

Comment: Would `client.on("error", err => {
    throw err; });
` work?

Comment: I suggest logging the error as throwing it again will leave it unresolved.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.